# Bootstrap-4 Target scrollspy navbar class

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am using scrollspy with bootstrap 4 and got it working. However, I am trying to target the navbar class when a navlink is active. Once the nav-link is active, I want to add a class to the navbar, once the link is not active, i want to remove the class. I've tried changing my classes to bg-light etc, but its still not working

Can you please help?

Here is my html.

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top d-block p-0 bg-transparent bg-light" id="fnav">
            <div class="navbar nav d-flex justify-content-between p-0">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#articles">Articles<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#schools">Schools</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#refs">References</a>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NavBar</a>                 
            </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the js

```
$(function() {

"use strict";

var topoffset =150;

//Scrollspy

$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '#fnav .navbar'
    offset: topoffset

});

//Addclass

$('.navbar .sticky-top').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {

var hash = $(this).find('nav-item.active a').attr('href');
if(hash  !== '#articles') {
    $('#fnav nav').addClass('infpage');
} else {
    $('#fnav nav').removeClass('infpage');
}

});
```